# Why did my minitest/pride alias break?

Tags: ruby, minitest

Silly, cosmetic question for everyone.

I take pride in my testing. That is, I like to use `minitest/pride`. Unfortunately, not everyone on my team is a fan, so I have activated it in the past using the command line instead of modifying the code by setting an alias to this:

```
RUBYOPT=-rminitest/pride bex rake`
```

(`bex` is an alias to `bundle exec`, and the default rake task runs our tests.)

Recently, we updated the ruby version of our project from 1.9.3 to 2.2.0. This has broken my alias, and now when I try to run it, I get this error instead:

```
/Users/cf5455/.rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- minitest/pride (LoadError)
from /Users/cf5455/.rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

My best guess as to why this is happening is that MiniTest was changed since our last Ruby version and `pride` has been renamed or moved, but I have not been successfully able to Google its new name or location.

Does someone know a way that I can fix my arguments to get `pride` working again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicated your error by switching to ruby 2.3.0. I just ran the tests before installing any gems.

I managed to get the tests running with your alias by simply doing a `gem minitest install`. Not sure if your problem is caused by the same reason since I'm using rbenv for managing my rubies and gems but it does feel like you are having a package management issue. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep. `gem install minitest` did the trick. I didn't even think about it because I thought Minitest was included with Ruby, which I guess it is, but they leave certain things out... In any event, thanks!